Freudenthal suspension homomorphism
I asked this question in MathStackExchange a couple of months ago, with little feedback, hence I try here.
The Hopf invariant $h(f)$ of a mapping $f:\mathbb S^{2m-1}\to \mathbb S^m$ is a homotopy invariant that gives information on $\pi_{2m-1}(\mathbb S^m)$ for $m$ even. Namely, there is always $f$ with $h(f)\ne0$ and such an $f$ generates a cyclic infinite group. However, $h(f)$ maybe zero and $f$ not null homotopic. This happen most often, but not for $m=2$ or $m=6$, and then the homotopy group above is cyclic infinite. My question is whether there are other $m$’s for which this happens. This essentially asks when the Freudenthal homomorphism $\pi_{2m-2}(\mathbb S^{m-1})\to\pi_{2m-1}(\mathbb S^m)$ is trivial.

Do you know about the EHP sequence? A good reference for this stuff is chapters 4 and 5 of J. Neisendorfer's book Algebraic Methods in Unstable Homotopy Theory.

Tyrone: no, I do not know that sequence. I’m not an specialist, I’ve come to the question somehow sideways. In fact, I was expecting some quick additional example or just to know if it is open. But I’ll try to look at that. Thanks.

My question was very modest, and checking some others on unstable homotopy groups of spheres here in OverFlow I've found that for $m=30$ the homotopy group is cyclic infinite. See:
N. Oda, On the 2-components of the unstable homotopy groups of spheres Parts I, II, Proc. Japan Acad. 53, Ser. A(1977), no. 6/7, 202-205/215-218,
where if I understand well it says $\pi_{59}(\mathbb S^{30})=\mathbb Z$.
And I guess my question was quite naive and clearly that of an outsider to the area.
